# Object doesnt have the same properties inside a function PHP

Tags: php

I've never worked with PHP before. I have the code below, which works fine.

```
$taxonomy = 'person';
// get the term IDs assigned to post.
$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
$separator = '';

if ( !empty( $post_terms ) && !is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {
  $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );
  $terms = wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&style=none&echo=0&taxonomy=' . $taxonomy . '&include=' . $term_ids );
  $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );
  echo $terms;
}
```

I tried to put this in a function so I can pass it an argument and call it.

```
function get_custom_tax($taxonomy) {
  // get the term IDs assigned to post.
  $post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
  $separator = '';

  if ( !empty( $post_terms ) && !is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {
    $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );
    $terms = wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&style=none&echo=0&taxonomy=' . $taxonomy . '&include=' . $term_ids );
    $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );
    echo $terms;
  }
}

$taxonomy = 'person';
get_custom_tax($taxonomy);
```

But for some reason this doesn't work... Stack tells me im trying to get the property `ID` of a non-object (I guess for `$post->ID`)

Whats going on here?

Comment: Variables in PHP aren't global, so inside the function, `$post` is undefined. You can read [variable scopes in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a score issue.

Changing my function to pass `$post` outside the function did the trick

```
function get_custom_tax($taxonomy, $post) {
      // get the term IDs assigned to post.
      $post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
      $separator = '';
    
      if ( !empty( $post_terms ) && !is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {
        $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );
        $terms = wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&style=none&echo=0&taxonomy=' . $taxonomy . '&include=' . $term_ids );
        $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );
        echo $terms;
      }
    }

    $taxonomy = 'person';
    get_custom_tax($taxonomy, $post);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function  is  missing post object.. you can declare as global or pass as a params

```
function get_custom_tax($taxonomy) {
  global $post;
  // get the term IDs assigned to post.
  $post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
  $separator = '';

  if ( !empty( $post_terms ) && !is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {
    $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );
    $terms = wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&style=none&echo=0&taxonomy=' . $taxonomy . '&include=' . $term_ids );
    $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );
    echo $terms;
  }
}

$taxonomy = 'person';
get_custom_tax($taxonomy);
```